# Completely remove remains of sysvinit

Tags: debian, systemd, sysvinit, migration, disk-cleanup

As opposed to people who [want](http://without-systemd.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_remove_systemd_from_a_Debian_jessie/sid_installation) to get rid of `systemd`, I want to **completely** and **safely remove** `sysvinit`.

I've been using `Debian` since *Debian 7.0 (Wheezy)*. Currently I'm using *Debian 9.0 (Stretch)*. During one of the system upgrades there was move from `sysvinit` to `systemd`.

`systemd` works fine for me, but I've noticed that system did **not** removed `sysvinit` completely.

- Why?
- How can I safely get rid off `sysvinit`?
- Is it safe to remove remains of `sysvinit` by:

  ```
  aptitude purge initscripts sysvinit sysvinit-utils
  ```

  or alternatively:

  ```
  apt-get remove --purge initscripts sysvinit sysvinit-utils
  ```

[BTW](http://www.tux.org/lkml/#contributors): [AFAIK](http://www.tux.org/lkml/#contributors) there is `systemd-sysvcompat` package (not installed) which probably somehow use `sysvinit`. I want to avoid problems which can be caused by removing remains of `sysvinit` which can be still somehow necessary for *Debian*.

Comment: You can remove `sysvinit` but the other two packages are still priority `Required` and can not be removed.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, I had misread the documentation before reading your comment, I updated my answer based on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why?*

Even though you can remove sysvinit a lot of system packages still rely on sysvinit style scripts.

*How can I safely get rid off sysvinit?*
*Is it safe to remove remains of sysvinit by...*

This depends on what you have installed on your system, if no system components depend on them then yes it is safe, apt will tell you. Note that you can use `rdepends` to check what depends on a package:

`apt-cache rdepends initscripts sysvinit-utils sysvinit`

If there is nothing you need printed as a dependency then removing them would be safe. **This won't be the case!!** You can do the removal as usual with `apt-get remove`.

---

Be aware that `initscripts` is not sysv specific, removing it will almost certainly destroy your system. See [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/initscripts)

If you are to remove sysvinit the /etc/rc*.d directories will still be present. If you look at the debate on [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Debate/initsystem/sysvinit) page you can see that there are many packages which still have sysvinit style scripts. Even though the old sysvinit directories are used this is actually managed by systemd.

I'm not sure why you want to get rid of the last traces of sysvinit but I would say it's not time yet, you will likely run into trouble. To build a system with no traces of sysvinit you will probably have to build your own distro although somebody may have already done this.

Comment: "I'm not sure why you want to get rid of the last traces of sysvinit but I would say it's not time yet": Is the long term plan to get rid of `sysvinit` completely? I would prefer to be able to choose between a configuration using only `systemd` and one using only `sysvinit`. In the same way as I can switch between `gnome`, `mate`, `kde`, and so on. Is this technically feasible? Is it planned?