# Each service runs twice while booting Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, boot, startup, init-script

[image: Boot Screen]I've just installed Fedora 25. However, while starting up the computer, each initialization service runs twice (see the attached picture), or are shown twice on the screen. How can I fix that? (I'm using ASUS N56V Laptop with Nvidia Geforce GT 650M)

Here is the result of `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service` :

```
UNIT                                                                                      LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
abrt-ccpp.service                                                                         loaded active exited  Install ABRT coredump hook
abrt-oops.service                                                                         loaded active running ABRT kernel log watcher
abrt-xorg.service                                                                         loaded active running ABRT Xorg log watcher
abrtd.service                                                                             loaded active running ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool
accounts-daemon.service                                                                   loaded active running Accounts Service
akmods-shutdown.service                                                                   loaded active exited  Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages
akmods.service                                                                            loaded active exited  Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages
alsa-state.service                                                                        loaded active running Manage Sound Card State (restore and store)
atd.service                                                                               loaded active running Job spooling tools
auditd.service                                                                            loaded active running Security Auditing Service
avahi-daemon.service                                                                      loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack
blk-availability.service                                                                  loaded active exited  Availability of block devices
bluetooth.service                                                                         loaded active running Bluetooth service
chronyd.service                                                                           loaded active running NTP client/server
colord.service                                                                            loaded active running Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles
crond.service                                                                             loaded active running Command Scheduler
cups.service                                                                              loaded active running CUPS Scheduler
dbus.service                                                                              loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
dracut-shutdown.service                                                                   loaded active exited  Restore /run/initramfs on shutdown
fedora-import-state.service                                                               loaded active exited  Import network configuration from initramfs
fedora-readonly.service                                                                   loaded active exited  Configure read-only root support
firewalld.service                                                                         loaded active running firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
gdm.service                                                                               loaded active running GNOME Display Manager
irqbalance.service                                                                        loaded active running irqbalance daemon
iscsi-shutdown.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Logout off all iSCSI sessions on shutdown
kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                 loaded active exited  Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel
libvirtd.service                                                                          loaded active running Virtualization daemon
lm_sensors.service                                                                        loaded active exited  Hardware Monitoring Sensors
lvm2-lvmetad.service                                                                      loaded active running LVM2 metadata daemon
lvm2-monitor.service                                                                      loaded active exited  Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling
lvm2-pvscan@8:9.service                                                                   loaded active exited  LVM2 PV scan on device 8:9
mcelog.service                                                                            loaded active running Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon
ModemManager.service                                                                      loaded active running Modem Manager
netcf-transaction.service                                                                 loaded active exited  Rollback uncommitted netcf network config change transactions
NetworkManager.service                                                                    loaded active running Network Manager
packagekit.service                                                                        loaded active running PackageKit Daemon
pcscd.service                                                                             loaded active running PC/SC Smart Card Daemon
polkit.service                                                                            loaded active running Authorization Manager
rngd.service                                                                              loaded active running Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon
rpcbind.service                                                                           loaded active running RPC Bind
rsyslog.service                                                                           loaded active running System Logging Service
rtkit-daemon.service                                                                      loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service
smartd.service                                                                            loaded active running Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
switcheroo-control.service                                                                loaded active running Switcheroo Control Proxy service
sys5_idl_dicomexstorscp.service                                                           loaded active exited  SYSV: This script is used to start and stop the IDL dicomex storage scp service.
sys5_idl_lmgrd.service                                                                    loaded active running SYSV: This script is used to start and stop the IDL network license manager.
systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                       loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight
systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service                                        loaded active exited  Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:asus::kbd_backlight
systemd-binfmt.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Set Up Additional Binary Formats
systemd-fsck-root.service                                                                 loaded active exited  File System Check on Root Device
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8376c70b\x2d7c22\x2d41e9\x2d972c\x2d77553b1d9914.service loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/8376c70b-7c22-41e9-972c-77553b1d9914
systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-fedora\x2dhome.service                                            loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/mapper/fedora-home
systemd-journal-flush.service                                                             loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
systemd-journald.service                                                                  loaded active running Journal Service
systemd-logind.service                                                                    loaded active running Login Service
systemd-modules-load.service                                                              loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules
systemd-random-seed.service                                                               loaded active exited  Load/Save Random Seed
systemd-remount-fs.service                                                                loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
systemd-sysctl.service                                                                    loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                        loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                            loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories
systemd-udev-settle.service                                                               loaded active exited  udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization
systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                              loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices
systemd-udevd.service                                                                     loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager
systemd-update-utmp.service                                                               loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
systemd-user-sessions.service                                                             loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions
systemd-vconsole-setup.service                                                            loaded active exited  Setup Virtual Console
udisks2.service                                                                           loaded active running Disk Manager
upower.service                                                                            loaded active running Daemon for power management
user@1000.service                                                                         loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000
user@42.service                                                                           loaded active running User Manager for UID 42
wpa_supplicant.service                                                                    loaded active running WPA supplicant
```

Here is the result of `journalctl -b -perr` :

```
kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000003) is beyond end of object (length 0x0) (20160831/exoparg2-427)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM] (Node ffff8ec5a64b5168), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20160831/psparse-543)
kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x000000003) is beyond end of object (length 0x0) (20160831/exoparg2-427)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM] (Node ffff8ec5a64b5168), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20160831/psparse-543)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM] (Node ffff8ec5a64cdf50), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20160831/psparse-543)
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: iccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: iccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: iccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: iccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled
kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: iccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled
avahi-daemon[1082]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
bluetoothd[1026]: Failed to obtain handles for "Service Changed" characteristic
abrtd[1059]: '/var/spool/abrt/Python3-2016-05-09-22:30:03-3154.new' is not a problem directory
abrtd[1059]: '/var/spool/abrt/oops-2016-12-12-20:08:35-1083-0' is not a problem directory
gnome-session-binary[1502]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
gnome-session-binary[1536]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
spice-vdagent[1723]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
spice-vdagent[2264]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
firewalld[1055]: ERROR: UNKNOWN_INTERFACE: 'wlp3s0' is not in any zone
firewalld[1055]: ERROR: UNKNOWN_INTERFACE: 'wlp3s0' is not in any zone
firewalld[1055]: ERROR: UNKNOWN_INTERFACE: 'wlp3s0' is not in any zone
```

Comment: can you post your result from `sudo systemctl list-units --type=service` ?(add this to your question)

Comment: I've just added it.

Comment: Looks normal! My guess was that you have to remove duplicate entries manually. Check again for duplicate entries there `sudo systemctl list-unit-files`

Comment: Thanks. There is no any duplicate entry in the output of the command you gave. I'm sure my system try to run these services twice in the beginning, but I couldn't find any reason for this yet. I checked the rc.d files as well. No any duplicate files...

Comment: OK. `rc.d` is the old `SysVinit` way to start services and `systemd` is the new. I'm not a Fedora user, but I guess you have them both activated, and that's why it's starting everything twice. Either get rid of sysVinit or systemd (I'd keep systemd which is the new linux and fedora 25 standard).

Comment: If so, how can I de-activate `rc.d`?

Comment: Fedora no idea! Debian: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214155/completely-remove-remains-of-sysvinit

Comment: Check this answer, to figure out if it's actually true (having sysvinit and systemd) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196166/how-to-find-out-if-a-system-uses-sysv-upstart-or-systemd-initsystem

Comment: I deleted rc.d/init.d folder (and all related things) and reboot the computer. Nothing has changed. I think my problem is different. My distro is using systemd.

Comment: Backup your data and reinstall Fedora 25 will certainly fix your problem. Sometimes this is the best choice when a distribution upgrade failed, or just wait for someone to answer your question here ...

Comment: The "you have both activated" theory is an interesting one but extremely unlikely. Fedora switched to systemd in Fedora 15, and there isn't an alternative init system available. systemd itself will handle old-style init scripts with its compatibility subsystem, but that wouldn't result in this behavior.

Comment: Can you run `journalctl -b -perr` to show error messages logged since boot? If that doesn't result in anything useful, maybe `journalctl -b -pwarning`?

Comment: I've added the result of the first command. Like the boot list, it also includes some duplicated errors... The output of the second command is quite long, no chance to paste it here :(

Comment: if you run `sudo systemd-analyze blame | sort -k2` you can actually see if services are started twice. If this is not the case, it might be printing it twice on boot for a unknown reason...

Comment: Can you look through the `-pwarning` output to see if anything seems... related or suspicious?

Comment: Same issue but I think it is just an issue with the boot screen (plymouth??) because in `/var/log/messages`, the messages are not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

It happen to me on kernel 4.9.* with Fedora 25. my laptop with dual graphic card.
I manage to solve the problem of "i**ccsense: Unknown sensor type 30, power reading disabled**" (based on your log) by modified my grub:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then add `acpi_backlight=video` inline with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX**

Now we need to rebuild the GRUB2 config file. Just run `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` or if you have EFI feature with you computer, please run `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` command, make sure you know which command to execute.

and then reboot.

Comment: It doesn't work. But, I'm sure that this is a problem arising from dual graphic card any more. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Remove the rhgb on `/etc/default/grub` and run the

```
grub2-mkconfig
```

as mentioned above. ( Just for ref. Been over a year )